# Spring перезаписывает переменную другого класса, почему так?

Tags: spring

Добрый день, я столкнулся со странной ситуацией в Spring и не могу понять, как ее исправить. Есть Класс А, в нем есть лист, который я получаю из другого класса С и передаю в метод класса В. В классе В я из этого листа удаляю некоторые элементы, это нужно для внутренних действий в методе класса В, когда количество элементов в листе достигнет нужного числа, то метод завершается.
Далее после выполнения метода класса В я вывожу лист класса А и он почему-то у меня содержит только те элементы, которые остались после выполнения метода класса В, то есть, как будто перезаписались. Причем когда я вывожу элементы из c.getList(), то тоже самое. Я всю голову сломал, уже 3й день, никак не могу понять и справить. Помогите плиииз. Моет это какая-то особенность Spring, может лишняя аннотация? Я спринг только изучаю и не знаю всех подводных камней.

```
@Service
public class A {

@Autowired
private B b;
@Autowired
private C c;

@Override
public void methodA() {
    List<W> tempList = c.getList();
    b.methodB(tempList);
    System.out.println(tempList); // содержит только элементы, которые остались после удаления в классе В (((
}
}
```

Класс В

```
@Service
public class B {

@Autowired
private A a;
@Autowired
private C c;

@Override
public void methodB(List<W> tempList) {
    // некие действия и условия с использованием классов С и А, 
    // но не затрагивая переменные, которые формируют Лист
    tempList.remove(n);
}
}
```

В классе С у меня так же есть, класс С помечен как @Service тоже

```
@Autowired
private A a;
```

Comment: Всё логично, A передаёт ссылку на объект списка, B изменяет этот объект. Если не хотите, чтобы изменялся исходный объект, передавайте ссылку на его копию.

Comment: это я понимаю, и копию передавал и в методе класса В переопределял, то есть созадавал новый объект лис и в него входной список помещал, работал с ним, но все равно меняется исходный, причем если вызвать метод получения класса С, то он тоже возвращает уже измененный список. Тут вообще не понимаю как так.